# view Prepared Statement

Tags: c#, sql

I am using the following situation:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into city (id, code, name, uf) values ??(@ id, @ code, @ name, @ uf);"
```

I wonder what would bring me in command after the format string supplied to the parameters

situation:

`insert into city (id, code, name, uf) values ??(5, 5, 'BIG COUNTRY', 'MS');` - for example

After the parameters have fed as I get this "string" already fed and move to a string??

My idea is to create a log, so need to get the parameters already filled in to generate a system log!

Comment: Don't think you can do that. The commandtext and parameters are sent to the sql server. You can iterate the parameters and do a string replace though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, have you considered using [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) instead?  If you're not using SQL Server, other RBDMS systems should have similar tools...

It would probably be less effort than adding this type of logging into your application, and it would also guarantee that you're seeing what is actually sent to your database, and that your logging code hasn't accidentally misinterpreted and incorrectly logged the query.

If you have an aversion to profiling, which would be justified if we're talking about a production database that won't be able to handle the overhead of profiling, you could assemble your log with something similar to the following:

```
var query = cmd.CommandText;

foreach (var p in cmd.Parameters)
{
    query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Profiler also won't slow down the response time as much as logging.  At least in as much that Profiler can only be set up while you need it, the logging would probably be on all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The query is sent to the DB with `@` parameter placeholders in place. The parameters are sent separately to the query... i.e. the client does not assemble a completed SQL statement.

Comment: +1 - The best you could do would be to iterate the parameter collection yourself and create the completed string manually.

Comment: ...assuming you can guarantee that it is never sent to the DB, otherwise you're into sql injection territory.

Comment: Correct. Personally, I would rather see the statement plus a parameter data set, in two different columns.